# VC++ Error: array instantiation with size from templated static const

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, static, constants

The following code works on gcc but fails on VS2012

```
class test_base{};

template<class DERIVED >
        class test_CRTP : public test_base
        {
                public:
                        const static int n_size;
        };

        //DEFAULT INITIALIZATION
template< class DERIVED >
        const int test_CRTP<DERIVED>::n_size = 3;

        //TEMPLATE SPECIALIZATION
        class test_spec : public test_CRTP<test_spec>{};


template<class test_T>
class MyClass{
public:
        void my_method(){
                int my_array[test_T::n_size];   //<-VS doesn't like this
        }
};

int main()
{
        MyClass<test_spec> oClass;
        oClass.my_method();
        return 0;
}
```

Error is:

> error C2057: expected constant expression

Is my code non standard compliant or is VS wrong?

<s>Is this fixed on newer versions?</s>

---

**EDIT:**
Based on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/, error persists on version `19.00.23720.0`

> ```
> Compiled with  /EHsc /nologo /W4 /c
> main.cpp
> main.cpp(26): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
> main.cpp(26): note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
> main.cpp(26): note: see usage of 'n_size'
> main.cpp(25): note: while compiling class template member function 'void MyClass<test_spec>::my_method(void)'
> main.cpp(33): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void MyClass<test_spec>::my_method(void)' being compiled
> main.cpp(32): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MyClass<test_spec>' being compiled
> ```

Comment: You can try at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net

Comment: @Niall Thanks for the link, seems I had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang and gcc accept the [code as posted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db0db1c6b53d4d1d).

MSVC is unhappy with the out of class initialisation of the `const static`, moving it to in the class allows MSVC to compile it. This issue is present in v19.00.23720.0 of the compiler ([as of this posting, online here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net)).

```
template <class DERIVED>
class test_CRTP : public test_base {
 public:
  const static int n_size = 3;
  //                     ^^^^^ moved it into the class.
};
```

Comment: So no way to override a static const member variable :(